# Automatically get the developer contact details from search API

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to automatically get the contact details (say an email) from the developers data that is returned by the Apple API

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

in obj-c ?

Answer (score 0):

That information is not available from the API.

What you can get using the search or lookup is the seller URL.

The [Enterprise Partner Feed](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html) does include support URL information if you wanted to try and use that.